# Visualize autocorrelation in multiple timeseries one dataset

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation

**Background**

Performing multiple linear regression analysis on dataset containing 21 time-series of 4 data points. Each data points represents 9 variables.

R² adjusted is not decreasing rapidly after adding more variables.

**Problem statement**

Since the 4 data points are a static window of a longer time-series I am thinking autocorrelation between the data-points is the problem.

**Question**

How to visualize or estimate if there is autocorrelation inside the different time-series?

**What I have tried:**

[image]

I think ACF of the residuals is not working since I have 21 time-series.

Comment: Linear regression isn't what you want when you have a time series. You seem to have lots of short time series, perhaps you want to look at longitudinal data analysis? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_study

Comment: Regarding whether you should pay attention to $R^2_{adj.}$ (perhaps only slightly relevant): ["Justification for and optimality of $R^2_{adj.}$ as a model selection criterion"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/408267). The short answer is, there is no answer justifying that in the thread.